# Doing an event for half the time of the first timer?

Tags: c#

So What I'm trying to do is basically.. Have 2 events, Lets called these Event 1 and Event 2, When Event 1 starts, a timer becomes activated, in which when it ends (the amount varies every time), It stores the elapsed time into a double variable

(Up to this stage it is all coded fine)

But my problem is.. I want Event 2 to run for half of the time that event 1 did.. And therefore I decided to store this value in another double variable, and setting the value divided by 2..

From here I'm wanting to then set up a sort of 'Countdown timer' So that once the amount of time has expired from the double variable with half the time stored, the event will stop.

Here is what I have so far..

```
//Creation of timer
Stopwatch Timer1 = new Stopwatch();

//Start the timer
Timer1.Start();

//Event 1 carries out here.. (Ain't going to bore you with this code)

//(Once ended) (ends once a condition is matched.. but cutting it short)..
//Timer1.Stop();

//Store amount in a double variable..
double dfull = Timer1.ElapsedMilliseconds;

//Half the amount in variable dhalf
double dhalf;
dhalf = dfull / 2;

//From here I want EVENT 2 to perform for the time stored in dC2B
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Was only being polite, but never mind, sorry about that, Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a new timer, `Start` it, and loop until its `ElapseMilliseconds` is `>= dhalf`; with the work you want to do inside the body of the loop.

Comment: Read the article I linked to, and you'll see why "polite" makes sense in a conversation, but not on [so]. We're not meant to be having a polite conversation. You're meant to ask a question, and get answers.

Comment: Yes okay, Fair enough John, I get your point, Thank you.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Ah yeah.. I See what you mean, I'll have a look what I can do, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Also, minor nitpick - these do not appear to be "events" as such - in C# events are a specific feature, so using the word with its general meaning is a bit confusing.

Comment: Okay, sorry I've only been programming for under a year, so I'm still learning

Comment: For me there is always room for politeness. You are asking someone for there time, so for me, a please and a thank you are never wasted in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using something like the following

```
System.Timers.Timer readyUpTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
readyUpTimer.Elapsed -= readyUpTimer_Elapsed;
readyUpTimer.Elapsed += readyUpTimer_Elapsed;
DateTime readyUpInitialised = DateTime.Now;
readyUpTimer.Start();
```

Then in your event handler

```
void readyUpTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - this.readyUpInitialised;
   if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > dhalf)
   {
      readyUpTimer.Stop();
      readyUpTimer.Dispose();
      // Do other things...
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi again, I've been trying to get this work, but came across some problems, the error points to this line: "TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - this.readyUpInitialised;" Any suggestions ?